# Query for regex pattern in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a regex for the following:

```
{u'device_type': u'Laptop'}
```

I have tried `[\W+\w]`. What would the correct pattern be?

Comment: That's a dictionary. `yourDict['device_type']`?

Comment: But, i need a regex pattern that will extract the whole string presented.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the desired output? And did you use curly brackets on your own accord or the data has curly brackets?

Comment: I wrote this: [\W+\w] @Cid

Comment: I want the whole string as the output but using a regex pattern. The string has curly brackets. @Poppinyoshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are expecting something like this:

```
import re

txt = "this is {u'device_type': u'Laptop'} a sentence."

match = re.search(r'\{.*\}', txt)
print(match.group(0))
# {u'device_type': u'Laptop'}
```

*Note*: This extracts anything between `{` and `}` including paranthesis.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't tell what format you want to find
you mean find whole string  like format { str1 : str2 }?  then it is

```
 '{.+:.+}'
```

Comment: I want the output as: {u'device_type': u'Laptop'}